Need help downloading the thumbnail of an issue
I was wondering if it is possible to download the thumbnail in an issue, because so far I have only seen how to download related files but nothing for the picture that is created when you create an issue, since the picture itself does not appear in the related section.
When I make the request to see the issues they have something called "snapshoturn" with a value like this: "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg", and I tried to find it using the files api but I couldnt, so I was wondering if it was possible to directly get the image , thank you for your help.

GET Issues API: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/issues-v2-issues-GET/ will not directly give you the attachments or thumbnails as compared to linkedDocuments. As for now this attribute: snapshotUrn on response is irrelevant.
The attribute that will help you form this endpoint is the: attachmentCount. It will give the number/count of related/attached files related to the issue.
You will then use the GET Issue Attachments API:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/issues-v2-attachments-GET/ to get all the attachments/files/thumbnails related to the issue.
The response comes with the attachment urn which contains bucket and object key.
You can then use Data management API to download the file: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/
Please may you check this BIM360 issue editor web app to help you see the attachments on the UI and be able to view on browser or download.
https://bim360-issue-editor.autodesk.io/
